# C style cast в С и С++

Tags: c++, c

C cast в С++ имеет следующую последовательность cast'ов:

```
const_cast
static_cast
static_cast + const_cast
reinterpret_cast
reinterpret_cast + const_cast
```

Есть ли отличия между C cast в С и С++?

Comment: Под C-cast вы имеете в виду `(type)expression`?

Comment: @avp, да, именно такой

Comment: Неясно, о каких "отличиях" вы говорите, если сразу понятно, что C-каст в С++ применяется в том числе и в контекстах, которые в принципе не могут возникнуть в С. Это отличие или не отличие? С и С++ - разные языки.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

О каких-то отличиях между "внешне похожими" конструкциями в совершенно разных языках программирования имеет смысл говорить только в существенно "похожих" контекстах использования, т.е. в коде, который можно условно рассматривать и как С, и как С++ одновременно. Придумать хорошие примеры таких различий непросто, особенно если требуется, чтобы различия были вызваны свойствами самого каста, а не посторонними различиями между языками.

1. В языке С преобразования указателей к целочисленным типам недостаточного размера приводят к неопределенному поведению. В языке С++ такие преобразования не разрешены вообще.
2. Язык С разрешает касты только из скалярных типов в скалярные типы. Язык С++, через вами же описанный механизм, разрешает касты чего угодно к чему угодно, если соответствующие преобразования определены.
3. ```
   struct A;
   struct B;

   struct B *foo(struct A *a)
   {
     return (struct B *) a;
   }
   ```

   Такое преобразование в языке С расценивает типы указателей как никак не связанные между собой, т.е. это преобразование фактически эквивалентно `(struct B *) (void *) a`.

   В языке С++, однако, компилятору в таком преобразовании [разрешается на свое усмотрение учитывать или не учитывать](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#5) информацию о возможном отношении наследования между типами `struct A` и `struct B`, даже если эта информация становится доступна (т.е. типы становятся *полными*) только ниже точки выполнения преобразования.
4. В языке С такая инициализация

   ```
   int *p = (int *) (2 - 2);
   ```

   порождает null-указатель. В языке С++ этого не гарантируется. (Хотя к самому касту это различие относится лишь опосредованно.)